EF Core: Filter on child data depending on parent data
Consider the following:
I have a database with Parents and Children. The Parent and Child tables both have a column called "Type". Each parent has a bunch of hundreds of children. I know ahead of time what children "Type" values I am interested in, but this is depending on the parent "Type" value.
So basically I want to create a construct like this and run it as part of the SQL.
  var myQueryDatas = new[] {
   new QueryData(){ParentType=1, NeedsChildTypes=new[]{101,142,105}}
   new QueryData(){ParentType=2, NeedsChildTypes=new[]{106,110,120,232}};

I want to get Parent instances with populated Children collections from the database, but only populated with the Children that satisfies the condition. Getting all children for every parent would create a massive memory footprint.
I have tried Dictionaries, Arrays and Tuples. I suspect that it could be solved using stored procedure or by creating the querydata in the database beforehand and then using some sort of table join. However, I want to avoid both those two things. The specific child types for a parent type may vary case by case, so it would be best to construct the SQL from C# code.
Is there any kind of conditional collection that will be accepted by the EF Core LINQ Provider?

Use ANY  : parents.Where(x => x.NeedsChildTypes.Any(y => y  == 101))

Suppose you have a QueryData structure defined as follows:
public class QueryData
{
    public int ParentType { get; set; }
    public int[] NeedsChildTypes { get; set; } = [];
}

And you've also defined Parent and Child classes:
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

To filter children based on ParentType and NeedsChildTypes, you can utilize the following code:
var query = context.Parent
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Include(p => p.Children
        .Where(c => 
            c.Parent.Type == 1 ? new[]{101,142,105}.Contains(c.Type) : 
            c.Parent.Type == 2 ? new[]{106,110,120,232}.Contains(c.Type) : false
        )
    );

For a more dynamic approach, a helper class QueryHelper with an extension method IncludeFilteredChildren has been devised. Here's how you can use it:
query = query
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .IncludeFilteredChildren
    (
        parent => parent.Children,
        child => child.Parent.Type,
        child => child.Type,
        queryDatas
    );

Below is the implementation of the QueryHelper class:
public static class QueryHelper
{
    public static IQueryable<TParent> IncludeFilteredChildren<TParent, TChild>(
        this IQueryable<TParent> query,
        Expression<Func<TParent, IEnumerable<TChild>>> childExpression,
        Expression<Func<TChild, int>> parentTypeAccessor,
        Expression<Func<TChild, int>> childTypeAccessor,
        QueryData[] queryDatas)
        where TParent : class
        where TChild : class
    {
        // Preparing LambdaExpressions for Include and Filter methods. It is the simplest way to build desired query.

        Expression<Func<IQueryable<TParent>, Expression<Func<TParent, IEnumerable<TChild>>>, IQueryable<TParent>>> includeTemplate = 
            (pQuery, pChildExpression) => pQuery.Include(pChildExpression);

        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TChild>, Func<TChild, bool>, IEnumerable<TChild>>> filterTemplate =
            (pChildren, pFilter) => pChildren.Where(pFilter);

        Expression<Func<int[], int, bool>> containsTemplate =
            (pValues, pChildProp) => pValues.Contains(pChildProp);


        // remember the parameters of the input expressions, they will be part of resulting query
        var parentParam = childExpression.Parameters[0];
        var childParam = childTypeAccessor.Parameters[0];

        // Getting parentType expression using childParam
        var parentType = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(parentTypeAccessor.Parameters[0], childParam,
            parentTypeAccessor.Body);

        Expression filterBody = Expression.Constant(false);

        for (var index = queryDatas.Length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
        {
            var data = queryDatas[index];

            // Just replace pValues and pChildProp from template 'pValues.Contains(pChildProp)' with actual values

            var contains = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(
                containsTemplate.Parameters[0],
                Expression.Constant(data.NeedsChildTypes),
                containsTemplate.Body
            );

            contains = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(
                containsTemplate.Parameters[1],
                childTypeAccessor.Body,
                contains
            );

            // combining into one condition expression
            filterBody = Expression.Condition(
                Expression.Equal(parentType, Expression.Constant(data.ParentType)),
                contains,
                filterBody
            );
        }

        // generating lambda expression for filter
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda(filterBody, childParam);

        var filter = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(
            filterTemplate.Parameters[1],
            filterLambda,
            filterTemplate.Body
        );

        filter = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(
            filterTemplate.Parameters[0],
            childExpression.Body,
            filter
        );

        var include = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(
            includeTemplate.Parameters[0],
            query.Expression,
            includeTemplate.Body
        );

        var includeDetailLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TParent, IEnumerable<TChild>>>(
            filter, parentParam);

        include = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(
            includeTemplate.Parameters[1],
            includeDetailLambda,
            include
        );

        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<TParent>(include);
    }
}


Ooh. I just left work. I will try that tomorrow. I need to inspect the resulting SQL.

Will add sample interface for generic function. Let me know if it is ok for you.

That will be excellent. You probably read my mind. I am a bit unsure how I would be able to turn the query object into a viable expression tree that would be the equivalent of your example.  I assume that if I start accessing objects instead of inlining constants such as"1" and "{102,104,106}", then the SQLLite query provider might throw in the towel and decide to filter client side instead.

If my proposed query works for you I can generate this expression. Just put in question QueryData definition.

Well, EF Core do not allow using parent property inside child property filter (who knows why).  Do you have backrefernce to Parent in Child? I have corrected original answer to show how to make query translatable.

This was a meeting heavy day. I highly appreciate your help and apologize for not responding much today. What do you mean by "Back reference"? The relationship in the db is a normal foreign key constraint. The entity model has navigation properties, but I assume that is not what you mean.

Does Child has navigation property Parent? So we can filter using c.Parent.Type == 1

Yes. They do. And it seems to work at least for a small set when I put it directly in line. So the task is then how to produce this "Where"-clause chain from the QueryData array.. Since the SQL will be quite large, there is probably a point at which it will decide to to at least some filtering client side, but if that threshold is predictable or detectable, I should probably split to multiple queries to the database.
